# How to run integration tests with bazel and docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, integration-testing, bazel, bazel-rules

I am writing a client SDK library and use bazel as the build system. I want to write a test which spin up two docker instances. One is a server, which can accept client requests. And the other is test binary of SDK library. So this is an integration test. My goal is that this test can be run with `bazel test //sdk/gtest_binary`. I know that bazel has a rule called sh_test, which can be used to trigger `docker compose` to start the two docker instances. I am wondering if this is achievable and is there a better way to run such integration tests? Should I use bazel docker rule?